# How to detect text change when autocompleting with a datalist attribute

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to have an input field react to text change events. The field has a `datalist` attribute to have autocompletion.

As I understand it, if I want to hook on the event as the user types (and not onBlur for example), I can use `ng-keyup`.

It works fine when a user types something, but not when he clicks a choice in the autocomplete box.

Is there another event I can listen to, to be able to fire an action when the user autocompletes his choice?

I also tried `ng-keydown` and `ng-keypress` without success.

Here's how I declared my input box:

```
<input id="id" list="someList" ng-model="myModel" ng-keyup="functionToCall()">
```

PS: I'm using Angular Dart.

edit:

So I retried the same thing, but I removed the `ng-model` attribute to make sure it wasn't causing friction while updating the model. So in my view :

```
<input id="bob" list="itemOptions" placeholder="Type an item name" ng-change="onItemNameChange2()" >
```

and in my component :

```
void onItemNameChange2() {
  print("changed");
}
```

And it only prints `changed` when `onBlur()`.

I also tried removing the list attribute:

```
<input id="bob" placeholder="Type an item name" ng-change="onItemNameChange2()">
```

and also only prints when `onBlur` (so just typing doesn't make the print() method to be called, I really have to leave the input field)

Comment: I don't see what are you using for auto complete

Comment: By autocomplete I mean selecting a suggestion from the datalist provided in `list="someList"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-change`. I made an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0hLvzav/1/) in JavaScript. It should work the same in Dart.

The `list` and the `ng-change` are attached to the input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myData" list="myList" ng-change="textChange()" />
<datalist id="myList">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}" />
</datalist>
```

`ng-change` isn't actually an html event it's an angular event triggered when the view data updates.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too, but it seems in Angular Dart that `ng-change` only fires when you blur the field.

Comment: is it possible that you have to set `ngModelOptions`? ng-change should fire each time the value in the input changes.

Comment: I haven't used that option myself.